# How to retrieve the depth of nested dictionaries in nested dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm not sure if I'm just having a brainblock here or if this is actually supposed to be a challenge, but I am having trouble figuring out how to check the depth of nested dictionaries if the keys are not known.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do (in the most simple/efficient way):

Optimally, there would be some way for me to determine the maximum depth of this dict, without knowing the keys and values -

```
nested_dict = {
  'nest1': {
    'nest2': {
       'nest3': 'val'
    },
    'unknown_key', 'val',
    'unknown_key': 'val'
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: You can look at each of the `.values()` of the dict, and test if any of those values is a dict. Then recursively test that dict's values.

Comment: Depending on the context, another data structure (such as a tree) may be more useful to store the data in.

Comment: I reformatted your data to highlight the syntax error for the first 'unknown_key' and duplicate key.

Comment: ... and if you don't want the recursive solution, use a queue to figure out which branches you need to explore.  I.e this is breath or depth first search algorithm that just happens to count.

Comment: @9769953 What does a tree data structure look like in Python?

Comment: @hdevs like this, or you can define class to model a tree (see also the package anytree if you want something already built).

Comment: @AllanWind Ah great, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if its a dict, if so, iterate over the values and recursively call the function get the max of the value.

PS : Dict was a syntax error, fixed it

```
def max_depth(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return 1 + max((max_depth(value) for value in d.values()), default=0)
    return 0

nested_dict = {'nest1': {'nest2': {'nest3': 'val'}, 'unknown_key': 'val', 'unknown_key': 'val'}}


print(max_depth(nested_dict))
```

Output
`3`

Comment: Thanks so much! This does it. Self taught programmer here, so I am not too familiar with recursion, but this works perfectly!

Comment: glad to know it works, play around with the code to understand how it works, if it helped you can choose to mark this solution as accepted @hdevs